# Why does opening a websocket in Safari 5.x thru 6.x invalidate the back cache?

Tags: safari, websocket, back

If I open a page in Safari for example

```
http://stackoverflow.com
```

then open the safari console and open a websocket, for example:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://ws.dslreports.com")
```

then I click a link on the page, and then press BACK the back cache is now ignored and the page is reloaded. I observe this on Safari 5.0 (which first introduced hixie websocket support) and latest Safari 6.x which uses hybi. Chrome and Firefox and other browsers supporting websockets do not seem to invalidate the back cache in this way.

As a result I can't enable websockets in Safari, because doing so invalidates the back cache for the first BACK to any page that created a connection. Subsequent BACKs work, however, unless the page makes an effort to reconnect, if so, EVERY page causes a back-cache miss.

Is this by design? any work around other than fall back to polling for Safari users. This would be a shame as Safari otherwise supports websockets just fine.

update: the unexpected invalidation behaviour does not happen with mobile Safari eg on IOS, a page can use a websocket and going to a new link and pressing back does not re-request the page from the server.

Comment: I solved the problem when I twigged that maybe if the websocket is closed correctly before the window unloads - using an onbeforeload handler - then the Safari issue is solved and that turned out to be the case.